# Как найти число, которое повторяется n-ое кол-во раз быстрее?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Такс, большие умы стэка, обращаюсь к вам за помощью.

Есть список с большим кол-вом цифр. Пример: `[1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2]`. Дело в том, что надо получить из этого списка то число, которое повторяется `n-ое` кол-во раз быстрее. То есть, `n = 3` и надо найти то число, которое повторится 3 раза быстрее остальных. В данном массиве это будет `1`. Никак не могу дотумкать как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: быстрее остальных - это как? чаще остальных? а.. понял - раньше,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 3
arr = [1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2]
dict_ = {el: 0 for el in set(arr)}

for el in arr:
    dict_[el] += 1
    if dict_[el] == n:
        print(el)
        break
```

Comment: Лучше defaultdict  вместо `dict_ = {el: 0 for el in set(arr)}` использовать...

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

способ 1:

```
data = [1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2]
n = 3

arr = dict(zip(set(data), [0] * len(data)))

for i in data:
    arr[i] += 1
    if arr[i] == n:
        print(i)
        break
```

способ 2:

очень неоптимально по скорости, но зато в 1 строку:

```
print([data[i] for i in range(len(data)) if data[:i+1].count(data[i]) == n][0])
```